# ubuntu 18 + XFCE : compose key no longer work after upgrading

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, xfce, compose-key

I have just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.

Things seems to work well except for the compose key that does not work anymore. I have a english (US) keyboard and in the configuration tools the compose key is set to <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>.

I am using XFCE (I think I have installed Xubuntu 16.04 from scratch).

```
~/tmp$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

~/tmp$ uname -a
Linux portable 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: did you go see inside *System Parameter* -> *Keyboard* -> *Shortcut* if your compose key still the same key?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. In the system parameters -> Keyboard -> Layout the compose key is set to Right Alt.

Comment: actually for any application that launch with XMODIFIERS="" myapp, then the compose key works fine. However if I just write myapp, the compose key does not work within the app.

Comment: I tested the above trick with emacs, scribus, thunderbird and xterm.

Comment: this seems to suggest that the problem is ibus. I have the following env: GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
can anyone help?